# Org Koma Letter export return args-out-of-range error

Tags: org-mode, org-export, spacemacs, latex

After updating my system I get the error at the bottom when exporting `C-c C-e C-s` (cursor on **My Subject**). Can someone explain me the error message in order to solve the problem?

my_letters.org:

```
* My koma letters
  :PROPERTIES:
  :EXPORT_AUTHOR: John Q
  :EXPORT_FROM_ADDRESS: Av. Foo, Acmetown
  :EXPORT_CLOSING: best regards
  :EXPORT_LATEX_CLASS: default-koma-letter
  :EXPORT_LATEX_HEADER: \AtBeginLetter{\setplength{toaddrhpos}{119mm}}
  :EXPORT_LATEX_HEADER+: \AtBeginLetter{\setplength{toaddrvpos}{60mm}}
  :EXPORT_LATEX_HEADER+: \AtBeginLetter{\setplength{toaddrindent}{0}}
  :EXPORT_LaTeX_HEADER+: \AtBeginLetter{\setplength{backaddrheight}{10}}
  :EXPORT_LaTeX_HEADER+: \AtBeginLetter{\setplength{toaddrheight}{25.5mm}}
  :EXPORT_LATEX_HEADER+: \AtBeginLetter{\addtokomafont{addressee}{\scriptsize}}
  :EXPORT_LATEX_HEADER+: \usepackage{pdfpages}
  :EXPORT_LATEX_HEADER+: \setlength\parindent{0pt}
  :EXPORT_OPTIONS: backaddress:t email:nil
  :EXPORT_OPTIONS+: foldmarks:nil phone:nil place:nil special-headings:nil subject:t
  :EXPORT_OPTIONS+: title-subject:t url:nil location:nil title:t
  :EXPORT_OPTIONS+: \n:t
  :END:
** My Subject
   :PROPERTIES:
   :EXPORT_Date: [2022-04-11 Mon]
   :EXPORT_TO_ADDRESS: Acme Inc.
   :EXPORT_OPTIONS+: title-subject:t location:t title:t
   :EXPORT_OPENING: Dear Mr. Foo
   :END:

Vivamus id enim.
```

---

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range 1 1137 1156)
  line-number-at-pos(1)
  vim-empty-lines-nlines-after-buffer-end(nil)
  vim-empty-lines-update-overlay()
  vim-empty-lines-mode(1)
  global-vim-empty-lines-mode-enable-in-buffers()
  run-hooks(after-change-major-mode-hook)
  run-mode-hooks(org-mode-hook)
  org-mode()
  (let ((org-mode-hook nil) (org-inhibit-startup t)) (org-mode))
  (let ((inhibit-modification-hooks t)) (let ((org-mode-hook nil) (org-inhibit-startup t)) (org-mode)) (set (make-local-variable 'org-superstar--font-lock-keywords) '(("^[ \11]*?\\(?:\\(?1:[-+]\\)\\|[ \11]\\(?1:\\*\\)\\) " (1 (org-superstar--prettify-ibullets))) ("^\\(?3:\\**?\\)\\(?2:\\*?\\)\\(?1:\\*\\) " (1 (org-superstar--prettify-main-hbullet) prepend) (3 (org-superstar--prettify-leading-hbullets) t) (2 (org-superstar--prettify-other-lbullet) t)))) (set (make-local-variable 'org-superstar-mode) 't) (set (make-local-variable 'org-target-link-regexp) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-macro-templates) '(("date" . "10.10.2019") ("title" . "How to append an argument to an external command i...") ("email" . "ra@notebox.ch") ("author" . "") ("input-file" . "koma.org") ("modification-time" . "(eval\n(format-time-string $1\n                     ...") ("n" . "(eval (org-macro--counter-increment $1 $2))") ("keyword" . "(eval (org-macro--find-keyword-value $1))") ("time" . "(eval (format-time-string $1))") ("property" . "(eval (org-macro--get-property $1 $2))"))) (set (make-local-variable 'org-table-may-need-update) 't) (set (make-local-variable 'org-latex-and-related-regexp) '"") (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-line-tags-regexp) '"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DONE\\|TODO\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(.*?\\)\\)??\\(...") (set (make-local-variable 'org-complex-heading-regexp-format) '"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DONE\\|TODO\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(\\[#.\\]\\)\\)?...") (set (make-local-variable 'org-complex-heading-regexp) '"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DONE\\|TODO\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(\\[#.\\]\\)\\)?...") (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-line-regexp) '"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DONE\\|TODO\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(.*?\\)\\)?[ \11...") (set (make-local-variable 'org-not-done-heading-regexp) '"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(TODO\\)\\)\\(?: +\\(.*?\\)\\)?[ \11]*$") (set (make-local-variable 'org-not-done-regexp) '"\\(TODO\\)") (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-regexp) '"\\(DONE\\|TODO\\)") (set (make-local-variable 'org-not-done-keywords) '("TODO")) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-log-states) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-sets) '(("TODO" "DONE"))) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-heads) '("TODO")) (set (make-local-variable 'org-done-keywords) '("DONE")) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-keywords-1) '("TODO" "DONE")) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-key-trigger) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-key-alist) '((:startgroup) ("TODO" . 116) ("DONE" . 100) (:endgroup))) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-kwd-alist) '(("TODO" sequence "TODO" "DONE" "DONE") ("DONE" sequence "TODO" "DONE" "DONE"))) (set (make-local-variable 'org-table-formula-constants-local) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-keyword-properties) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-tag-groups-alist) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-current-tag-alist) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-file-tags) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-startup-with-inline-images) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-link-descriptive) 't) (set (make-local-variable 'buffer-file-name) '"/home/user/koma.org") (set (make-local-variable 'default-directory) '"/home/user/org/") (set (make-local-variable 'buffer-file-coding-system) 'utf-8-unix) (insert #("* My pingen letters\n  :PROPERTIES:\n  :EXPORT_AUTHO..." 0 1 (composition (0 1 [9673]) face (org-superstar-header-bullet org-level-1) fontified t) 1 19 (face org-level-1 fontified t) 19 22 (fontified t) 22 34 (face org-drawer fontified t font-lock-fontified t) 34 37 (fontified t) 37 52 (face org-special-keyword font-lock-fontified t fontified t) 52 53 (fontified t) 53 59 (face org-property-value fontified t) 59 62 (fontified t) 62 83 (face org-special-keyword font-lock-fontified t fontified t) 83 84 (fontified t) 84 101 (face org-property-value fontified t) 101 104 (fontified t) 104 120 (face org-special-keyword font-lock-fontified t fontified t) 120 121 (fontified t) 121 133 (face org-property-value fontified t) ...)) (narrow-to-region 1137 1156) (goto-char 1137))
  (lambda nil (let ((inhibit-modification-hooks t)) (let ((org-mode-hook nil) (org-inhibit-startup t)) (org-mode)) (set (make-local-variable 'org-superstar--font-lock-keywords) '(("^[ \11]*?\\(?:\\(?1:[-+]\\)\\|[ \11]\\(?1:\\*\\)\\) " (1 (org-superstar--prettify-ibullets))) ("^\\(?3:\\**?\\)\\(?2:\\*?\\)\\(?1:\\*\\) " (1 (org-superstar--prettify-main-hbullet) prepend) (3 (org-superstar--prettify-leading-hbullets) t) (2 (org-superstar--prettify-other-lbullet) t)))) (set (make-local-variable 'org-superstar-mode) 't) (set (make-local-variable 'org-target-link-regexp) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-macro-templates) '(("date" . "10.10.2019") ("title" . "How to append an argument to an external command i...") ("email" . "ra@notebox.ch") ("author" . "") ("input-file" . "koma.org") ("modification-time" . "(eval\n(format-time-string $1\n                     ...") ("n" . "(eval (org-macro--counter-increment $1 $2))") ("keyword" . "(eval (org-macro--find-keyword-value $1))") ("time" . "(eval (format-time-string $1))") ("property" . "(eval (org-macro--get-property $1 $2))"))) (set (make-local-variable 'org-table-may-need-update) 't) (set (make-local-variable 'org-latex-and-related-regexp) '"") (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-line-tags-regexp) '"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DONE\\|TODO\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(.*?\\)\\)??\\(...") (set (make-local-variable 'org-complex-heading-regexp-format) '"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DONE\\|TODO\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(\\[#.\\]\\)\\)?...") (set (make-local-variable 'org-complex-heading-regexp) '"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DONE\\|TODO\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(\\[#.\\]\\)\\)?...") (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-line-regexp) '"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DONE\\|TODO\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(.*?\\)\\)?[ \11...") (set (make-local-variable 'org-not-done-heading-regexp) '"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(TODO\\)\\)\\(?: +\\(.*?\\)\\)?[ \11]*$") (set (make-local-variable 'org-not-done-regexp) '"\\(TODO\\)") (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-regexp) '"\\(DONE\\|TODO\\)") (set (make-local-variable 'org-not-done-keywords) '("TODO")) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-log-states) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-sets) '(("TODO" "DONE"))) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-heads) '("TODO")) (set (make-local-variable 'org-done-keywords) '("DONE")) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-keywords-1) '("TODO" "DONE")) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-key-trigger) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-key-alist) '((:startgroup) ("TODO" . 116) ("DONE" . 100) (:endgroup))) (set (make-local-variable 'org-todo-kwd-alist) '(("TODO" sequence "TODO" "DONE" "DONE") ("DONE" sequence "TODO" "DONE" "DONE"))) (set (make-local-variable 'org-table-formula-constants-local) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-keyword-properties) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-tag-groups-alist) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-current-tag-alist) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-file-tags) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-startup-with-inline-images) 'nil) (set (make-local-variable 'org-link-descriptive) 't) (set (make-local-variable 'buffer-file-name) '"/home/user/org/koma.org") (set (make-local-variable 'default-directory) '"/home/user/org/") (set (make-local-variable 'buffer-file-coding-system) 'utf-8-unix) (insert #("* My pingen letters\n  :PROPERTIES:\n  :EXPORT_AUTHO..." 0 1 (composition (0 1 [9673]) face (org-superstar-header-bullet org-level-1) fontified t) 1 19 (face org-level-1 fontified t) 19 22 (fontified t) 22 34 (face org-drawer fontified t font-lock-fontified t) 34 37 (fontified t) 37 52 (face org-special-keyword font-lock-fontified t fontified t) 52 53 (fontified t) 53 59 (face org-property-value fontified t) 59 62 (fontified t) 62 83 (face org-special-keyword font-lock-fontified t fontified t) 83 84 (fontified t) 84 101 (face org-property-value fontified t) 101 104 (fontified t) 104 120 (face org-special-keyword font-lock-fontified t fontified t) 120 121 (fontified t) 121 133 (face org-property-value fontified t) ...)) (narrow-to-region 1137 1156) (goto-char 1137)))()
  org-export-copy-buffer()
  org-export-as(koma-letter t nil nil (:output-file "koma.tex"))
  org-export-to-file(koma-letter "koma.tex" nil t nil nil nil (lambda (file) (org-latex-compile file)))
  (let ((file (org-export-output-file-name ".tex" subtreep)) (org-koma-letter-special-contents)) (org-export-to-file 'koma-letter file async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist #'(lambda (file) (org-latex-compile file))))
  org-koma-letter-export-to-pdf(nil t nil nil)
  (org-open-file (org-koma-letter-export-to-pdf nil s v b))
  (if a (org-koma-letter-export-to-pdf t s v b) (org-open-file (org-koma-letter-export-to-pdf nil s v b)))
  (lambda (a s v b) (if a (org-koma-letter-export-to-pdf t s v b) (org-open-file (org-koma-letter-export-to-pdf nil s v b))))(nil t nil nil)
  org-export-dispatch(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil)
  call-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil nil)
  command-execute(org-export-dispatch)
```

Comment: This seems to be an artifact of `global-vim-lines-mode-enable-in-buffers`. You can make sure that that is the case by deleting the function  from `after-change-major-mode-hook`. Assuming that it then works, complain to whoever defined that function.

Comment: The front page of the [project](https://github.com/jmickelin/vim-empty-lines-mode) has an explanation: basically, the maintainer has not found the time to fix various issues similar to the one you complain about. I would suggest deleting that function from the hook permanently.

Answer (score 1):

As the [project page](https://github.com/jmickelin/vim-empty-lines-mode) states, the project has bugs and the maintainer does not have enough time to fix them. I would suggest that you find the place in your init file(s) where you add the function `global-vim-lines-mode-enable-in-buffers` to the `after-change-major-mode-hook` hook variable. It probably looks something like this:

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook #'global-vim-lines-mode-enable-in-buffers)
```

Just delete this line. If you want to try removing it temporarily to check that it is indeed the culprit, you can eval the following expression (perhaps in your `*scratch*` buffer):

```
(remove-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook #'global-vim-lines-mode-enable-in-buffers)
```

But I really think that you should remove it permanently: buggy packages do not become bug-free with time unless somebody is working actively on the bugs. This does not seem to be the case here.

**Edit**: I checked the package and it does not seem to be adding the function to the hook. At this point, I would try `emacs -Q` (or its doom equivalent: I assume there is one but I don't know for sure) and check the `after-change-major-mode-hook` to make sure that it does not contain `global-vim-lines...` by default. Then do the same thing with `emacs -q`. If in both of these cases the hook does not contain the `global-vim-lines...` function, then it's got to be in your init file(s). Search for the hook and/or the function separately and see what you come up with.

Comment: There's no `global-vim..` line in my config (.spacemacs.d/init.el). Thinking of vim though I'm thinking of the `emacs-evil` package as part of spacemacs

Comment: Examine the value of the hook with `C-h v after-change-major-mode-hook`. If `global-vim-lines-mode-enable-in-buffers` is in it, then *somebody* must have added it. It may be the package itself, in which case, if you remove the package, then it should go away.